# activesheet filter debug- Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to sort this mastersheet by the banker. There is a bug that says Type Mismatch on the code sName= arBanker (n,1). Does anyone know why? Many thanks!!!!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub separate_by_banker()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, arBanker As Variant
    Dim n As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim foldername As String, sName As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Banker")
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arBanker = ws.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow).Value2

    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Asia (PC)")
    iLastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = wsData.Range("A1:Y" & iLastRow)
    
    ' make folder for workbooks
    foldername = wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    MkDir foldername

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To UBound(arBanker)
        sName = arBanker(n, 1)
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' 1 sheet
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Name = sName
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=sName
        rng.Copy
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Paste
        wbNew.SaveAs foldername & "\" & sName & ".xlsx"
        wbNew.Close False
    Next

    wsData.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " files created in " & foldername, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: What is in cell A2 on the Banker sheet?

Comment: You could try `sName = CStr(arBanker(n, 1))` but I'd also like to know what content of the array is throwing the error. You can step through the code with F8 to see what the value is, if it's not in the first cell.